# Is there any way to convert html tags to react-pdf tags in React?

Tags: javascript, pdf, tags, react-pdf, html-pdf

I am going to convert HTML contents to react-pdf tags using [react-pdf render](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-pdf/renderer) in React.

```
import {
  Document,
  Page,
  View,
  Text,
  Image,
  StyleSheet
} from '@react-pdf/renderer';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  page: {
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    padding: 24
  },
  h1: {
    fontSize: 24,
    fontWeight: 500
  },
  h5: {
    fontSize: 12,
    fontWeight: 500
  },
  ...

const ProposalPDF = ({ content }) => {

  return (
    <Document>
      <Page size="A4" style={styles.page}>
        <View style={styles.header}>
          <View>
            <Image
              source="/static/logo.png"
              style={styles.brand}
            />
          </View>
          <View style={styles.flexAlignRight}>
            <Text style={[styles.h1]}>
              Title
            </Text>
            ...
```

I need to add HTML contents to the `Document`, but they are showing as pure HTML.
What I tried is that I used `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` inside Text tag.
But it didn't work at all.

```
<Text style={styles.body1} dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: content }} />
```

What should I use for displaying html contents as PDF view?
The HTML contents are produced by Quill editor.
So there are some HTML tags including `strong`, `h1`, `li`, `p`, `br`, `ol`, `ul`, etc.

Comment: i hope someone has a answer for this, i am also having problem with this one

Comment: Have you found a solution to the problem above?

Answer (score -1):

I ended up finding a great resource that helped me find a solution here: https://levelup.gitconnected.com/elegant-pdfs-from-user-generated-content-in-react-656b79533fee

I have a helper function that uses DraftJS to filter through the HTML and convert to react-pdf friendly tags.